# Xamarin Forms how to take pictures using the Dependency Service

Tags: xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.android, android-camera, xamarin.forms

First of all, I'm new to Xamarin, but I'm already loving it's concept of maximizing code share between plataforms.

I followed this tutorial to implement camera access in a blank new Xamarin Forms (2.3) project with success. Simple and great example btw.

However I don't like the way that I have to depend on the Activity class in Android to accomplish it.

I'm trying to refactor the code to a more elegant way by using the Dependency Service (just like this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/text-to-speech/) without success.

It dosen't work because in the Xamarin Guide there is no need to have an Activity inside the Android interface implemantation.

The main problems are:

1. After creating the service interface (ICamera), when I try to implement the ShouldTakePicture method (on Android Camera service) I NEED an Activity to call this:`StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);`
2. And also to retrieve the Image at `OnActivityResult()`. Can someone point me a way to do this without the Activity (I'm just looking for a way to deal with it without depending on Activitys).

Is there a way to accomplish it? My desire is to call the ICamera. ShouldTakePicture() through Xamarin.Forms in different places with minimum (or non) implementation on Android Activitys.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Media Plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/mediaplugin) for taking photos. Installed it in Nuget manager and used in PCL.

```
var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    Name = "IMG_1.jpg"
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This will do!